# ImmNotifyIME failed while some IMM functions like ImmGetContext works well

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ime

I'm writing a program using IME composition on Windows 10.
The program uses `DefWindowProc` to handle all `WM_IME_` message in a specific thread and check IMM context in another thread.

When I want to change the position of input method, the following code works well:

```
HWND idefhwnd = fpImmGetDefaultIMEWnd (hwnd);
::SendMessageW (idefhwnd, WM_IME_CONTROL, IMC_SETCOMPOSITIONWINDOW,
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&cpf)));
```

While following code failed:

```
HIMC hImc = fpImmGetContext (hwnd);
fpImmSetCompositionWindow (hImc, &cpf);
fpImmReleaseContext (hwnd, hImc);
```

I want to know what situation caused `fpImmNotifyIME` to fail or is there any other way to temporarily make the candidate box invisible. Thanks.

***Details:***

To be compatible with old compiler, I use dll as follow:

```
hModImm32 = ::GetModuleHandleW (L"Imm32.dll");
fun = ::GetProcAddress (hModImm32, funcname);
```

Some imm functions are working properly. I used `ImmAssociateContextEx` to disable IME temporarily. It works well.

```
using iace_t = decltype(ImmAssociateContextEx);
iace_t* fpImmAssociateContextEx = mcl_get_immfunc<iace_t>("ImmAssociateContextEx");
if (!fpImmAssociateContextEx) return false;

fpImmAssociateContextEx (hwnd, NULL, IACE_CHILDREN);
```

But I found out that this cannot close the candidate box when typing. So I'm trying to notify input method to close window when disabling it with following code before `fpImmAssociateContextEx` is called. (just as [How to hide the Input Method Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108591/how-to-hide-the-input-method-editor/70111565))

```
HIMC himc = fpImmGetContext (hwnd); // himc != nullptr
fpImmNotifyIME ( himc, NI_COMPOSITIONSTR, CPS_CANCEL, 0 );
fpImmNotifyIME ( himc, NI_CLOSECANDIDATE, 0, 0 );
```

All `fpImmNotifyIME` returned `FALSE` and did nothing.

Comment: Whether you could try to use unclick “Use predictive input system” to turning off the candidate box? What's the error message of the ImmNotifyIME? Could you please provide a sample to help us reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in **'*The program handles message in a specific thread and check IMM context in another thread.*'** `ImmNotifyIME()` and `ImmSetCompositionWindow()` default to using the `HWND` of the thread calling the functions. The solution is to call these functions by notifying the thread responsible for processing the message loop through `SendMessage()`.